# Alternando telas com o mesmo arquivo XML

Tags: java, android, xml, classes

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo educacional (com vários exercícios sobre java e explicações) para Android, mas possuo uma dúvida: o aplicativo torna-se muito pesado se eu criar uma *activity* (com um arquivo XML) por exercício ou tela com explicações, não é? 
Como eu faria para resolver esse problema? No caso, meu *app* teria diversos tipos de exercícios, como exercícios em que o usuário marca a resposta correta, seleciona o bloco de código correto ou até mesmo escreva uma linha de código necessário para a questão.

Há alguma maneira de usar o mesmo modelo de tela(XML)/exercício para um tipo específico de exercício? Tipo, usar um modelo de tela para responder todas as questões de assinalar, e outro modelo para outro tipo de exercício?

**P.S:** já tenho experiência em Java, porém comecei a trabalhar com Android agora.

Comment: Na verdade, você só precisa de uma `activity` para gerenciar quantos exercícios você quiser. 100, 200...

Comment: acredito que a melhor solução pro seu caso seria voce cadastrar as questões que voce quiser num db sqlite e montar suas telas a partir dessa base usando fragments, voce também pode escrever as questões num arquivo texto e colocar esse arquivo numa pasta /res/raw ou mesmo numa pasta assets, dai ficaria mais fácil e dinâmico, visto que voce pode ate adicionar mais questões sem ter de alterar ou implementar novos layouts para essas novas perguntas.

Comment: Mas pretendes usar o mesmo XML então para todas as perguntas? Ou para cada exercício criar um XML ( é que isso é capaz de ficar muito pesado) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível reutilizar um único arquivo XML em diversas *activities*.

Para alterar propriedades de *views* declaradas no XML, atribua um id a elas:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="This is a placeholder text"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
```

E busque sua referência em tempo de execução:

```
TextView questionTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
questionTitle.setText("Nome da questão");
```

Neste caso estou trocando o texto exibido no *TextView* para "Nome da questão".

Pensando desta forma, você poderia criar *layouts* XML que seriam os "esqueletos" das questões, e preenchê-los em tempo de execução.

---

Quanto ao número de *Activities* que podem existir, isso será uma escolha sua. Como o **IAMLuc** mencionou, é possível ter somente uma *Activity* que gerencie todas as suas questões. Você também poderia ter uma *Activity* para cada tipo de questão. Ou até utilizar Fragments, como o **Armando Marques Sobrinho** sugeriu.

Você deve avaliar qual opção será mais fácil de manter, sem gerar código duplicado.